# Can I upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 OFFLINE using an ISO image of 22.04?

Tags: upgrade, iso, offline

My connection is capped at 80 KB/sec (640 Kb/sec). It would take over 7 hours to upgrade online, and likely crash due to several factors, with catastrophic outcome.
Can I just use an ISO image and upgrade from it offline instead?

Answer (score 0):

As per [the release notes for 22.04 LTS](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-notes/24668):

> There are no offline upgrade options for Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server. Please ensure you have network connectivity to one of the official mirrors or to a locally accessible mirror and follow the instructions above.

Unfortunately this means that you will need to perform a reinstall if you would like to upgrade while offline.